# CSS problem: Gap between background-color (height: 100%) and border

Tags: css, height, border, background-color

I am trying to make an experience bar with 2 `<div>` area. the longer `<div>` outside for the frame and the shorter  inside for the current experience.

when I use {height: 100%} for inside `<div>` to fill up space, there is a gap between border and background-color when I change the display size of the browser to some certain %.

I tried it in chrome and edge browser and they have the same problem. I can fix the gap by changing {height: 101%}. I just wonder why there's a gap for 100% in some certain display sizes.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bar-frame {
  background-color: grey;
  border: solid 13px black;
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#bar {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="bar-frame">
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I expect there's no gap in the bar, but there's a gap show up in some certain display sizes.

CODEPEN link: https://codepen.io/ququ929/pen/zQWrZQ

English is my second language, hope you can understand the problem, thank you.

[picture to show the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPXXc.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iecXx.png)

[what I expect for all display size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYFiG.png)

Comment: It is a rounding issue at certain sizes.

Comment: I got the point, so that's some binary problem behind the screen, all we can do is bypass it or give it another code to fix it, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `border: 1px solid grey` in you `#bar` CSS will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
#bar {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100%; width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: this is better than change height to 101%. Thank you

Comment: If the answer help you out, Please marked as correct. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you.